# how to display rounded values when dragging a Jquery slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, coldfusion, slider

I have a Jquery Mobile slider, for which I'm setting min/max and default values.

All values from the database are xxx,yy so I'm rounding all default values being placed into the page (using Coldfusion8):

```
<input  type="range" 
        data-mini="true" 
        name="xxx" 
        id="xxx" 
        class="max" 
        value="#XMLFormat(trim( Round(var.max_price )))#" 
        min="#var.min_price#" 
        max="#var.max_price#" />
```

My problem is, when I start to drag the slider, the "dragged" values are ending with decimals **,95**.

[image]

**QUESTION:**
How do I round the "dragged values"? Can't be the database, because I'm not polling it on dragging. Is this something I need to do in the HTML?

Comment: u can add this code and jquery in jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would round the min-price always down with `fix()` and round the max-price always up with `ceiling()`. Then set `step="1"` on range-slider.

```
<input  type="range" 
        data-mini="true" 
        name="xxx" 
        id="xxx" 
        class="max" 
        value="#XMLFormat(trim( Round(var.max_price )))#" 
        min="#fix(var.min_price)#" 
        max="#ceiling(var.max_price)#"
        step="1" />
```